# Parsing JSON Using F# (not Serialization)

Tags: json, parsing, f#

I am trying to build a tree (via a discriminated union type) in my F# application to represent my data generically. I researched what was available on the web and I have found things like the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). The problem is, I am not really serializing the data into a specific object.

Here is my discriminated union:

```
type ParameterTree =
    | End
    | Node of string * Dictionary<string, Parameter> * ParameterTree
```

I basically want to be able to read in from a stream and populate the ParameterTree with the data I am getting from the stream (including appropriate parent/child relationship). I am stuck on where to begin with this. If anybody can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the best option would be to use some more lightweight library that simply gives you the parsed key/value pairs in some .NET dictionary and then transform the data to a nice F# discriminated union.

The [Json.NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) has a `JObject.Parse` method which seems to be doing exactly that. Here is a C# example from their web site:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
string name = (string)o["Name"];
JArray sizes = (JArray)o["Sizes"];
string smallest = (string)sizes[0];
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to convert `JObject` and `JArray` structures to your union type.

Comment: Hi @Tomas - I appreciate your answer (already accepted), but, I'm running into a minor problem. The reader I am creating is somewhat generic - the problem is defined by the user. Is there a way to iterate through the various properties and objects using your method (enumerate over them, generically)? I can't seem to find a way to do that. (I don't know what the fields will be beforehand - all I know is that it will be a tree structure).